# Flutter named parameters attribute value

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question i flutter
in some named parameters like color :
Or physics :  in listviewbuilder the value is Colors.some color name in color and
Neverscroll in physics
My question is how to know that the attribute take this value although I tried to search in source code in flutter but i couldn't find out how
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Theses are known as named constructor. Check this class

```dart
class MyClass {
  final int a;
  final String b;
  final double c;

  MyClass({required this.a, required this.b, this.c = 1.0});
}
```

Once you like to use this class you need to provide data like

```
MyClass(a: 1, b: "");
```

Note here a and b are required but c is using default value. Also, you can make nullable variables.

A good start guide will be [language-tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)